# isPortrait in LWUIT 1.4 is not working?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, orientation-changes

I'm using LWUIT 1.4. I want to lock the orientation for landscape. So, I used

```
Display.getInstance().isPortrait();
```

But it says can't find symbol for `isPortrait()`?

Can anyone tell  why this method not available in LWUIT1.4?

Comment: do you have API documentation for LWUIT 1.4? or link to that documentation?

Answer (score 2):

First...are you importing the correct `Display`? Is important that you don't import the lcdui `Display`.
Second...the correct method is lockOrientation(boolean portrait) . You must write `Display.getInstace().lockOrientation(true);`. I think is `true`value...try to do that.

Comment: Third. Weren't these features added in 1.5 ;-)

Comment: I used this lines but still i'm getting orientation in NokiaN8. 

boolean showPortrait = Display.getInstance().isPortrait();
//Display.getInstance().lockOrientation(true);
Display.getInstance().lockOrientation(showPortrait);

Comment: Sorry, If you want to put your app in landscape mode put the value to false. This should work. From the API:
lockOrientation(boolean portrait) 
          On devices that return true for canForceOrientation() this method can lock the device orientation either to portrait or landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

Well i have made it working  by getting screen height and width .

if width is less than height just discarding it and if above allowing it

implemented same kind of scenario in Lwuit as well as Blackberry UIApplication and its working

Comment: `if (Display.getInstance().getWidth() > Display.getInstance().getHeight()) {
//landscape
} else {
//portrait
}`